# can I set an older version of java as a default for certain programs?

Tags: jre, java

I have java 1.6 and 1.7 installed on my computer. I want to use 1.7 for everything except a single webapp that doesn't run on 1.7 well. Can I get some help?

EDIT:
 On windows but I need a fix for every OS

Comment: what OS are we talking about?

Comment: I'm using windows but I need it for every os

Comment: By "webapp" do you mean a Java applet running in the browser, for which you don't have the code?

Comment: This is one of the things doable with applets and java web start.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that PATH environment variable contains the bin directory of the 1.7 JRE. That way, everytime you use

```
java SomeClass
```

you'll use Java 7.

For your specific webapp, launch it using the absolute path of the Java 6 command:

```
/absolute/path/to/java6/bin/java ...
```

or

```
c:\absolute\path\to\java6\bin\java ...
```

on Windows.

Comment: This is a noob question but, where do I do this?

Comment: in your console/shell window. Start menu - Execute - type 'cmd' <Enter>. If you want to be able to double-click on something to start a java app, create a .bat or .cmd script (under windows) or a .sh script (under Linux/MacOS).

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above states, you can just use the absolute path to the Java compiler for a webapp to use some specific version.

Another option for some applications is to add some switch or setting in an initialization file (typically has a .ini extension on Windows) - e.g. eclipse.ini. Some other Java programs like Sql Developer prompt to choose the version used, if the default is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

"For every OS" — that is without a doubt not possible to give, but I can add specifics on Debian based systems to the existing answers.

Make sure the wanted Java version is installed and run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This will prompt you to choose which of the registered Java versions will be the target of `/usr/bin/java`, and thus decide the default Java binary.